# Entity Framework create a logical relationship

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I'm mapping a database, which has no physical relationships whatsoever. But tables are related. (they use SP to do their relationships).

Is there a way I can logically create the relationship on the data model I generated? I'd love if eager loading works with this also (even tho no physical relationship exists).

Comment: What you mean by: *they use SP to do their relationships*?

Comment: @Ladislav You know how nosql databases work and your application logic deals witht he relationships for you? Thats how they use their SP.

Comment: But EF doesn't support such approach. Your database must be designed "correctly" to support relations = it must have colmns with related keys and it mst have referential integrity even if relatins are not defined in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the relationships manually in the model.

One way to do this is to open the edmx file using an xml editor and edit it directly.

If you create a test database with a few related tables and then generate a model from that database, you can see how relationships are defined in an edmx file.